# Can not copy paste to create an appointment from task

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2007, I can select-copy-paste a task from TODO list to Calendar to make an appointment, it seems to be absent in Outlook 2013, how can I get that option back?

Comment: Works for me in Outlook 2013, but I had to use keyboard shortcuts (ctrl+c, ctrl+v)...  How are you trying to accomplish it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Just highlight the task and move it to your calendar (at the bottom of your page), it will open the calendar, then just change the dates, and your task will be in your calendar.